# SWIFT: Compass-like animation

Tags: swift, animation, motion, deviation

I have configured Core Motion manager in order to access the rotation coordinates and use them to animate deviation, like in native compass application. So here is what I want to achieve:

[image: Green curve]

It is this green line showing the deviation. I've tried simply to animate bezier's curve by setting it in

```
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler:)
```

method, but it didn't work - the animation was starting each time coordiantes was changing and filling the center with lines. I suppose that this animation should run on different thread, and motion manager should update only end point of bezier's curve. I have no idea how to do it. Any tips or examples would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the code you’re using to set up the bézier overlay and animate it?

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to do it in different way. Instead of animation, I just transform the background of this wheel using motion manager.